# I cannot access Jupyter Notebook from remote HPC system

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, remote-access, hpc

What I want to do is connecting Jupyter Notebook to a remote HPC system.
So, firstly I get the access to the HPC with the following line of code:

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=true a06upi0e@cometa.hpc.cineca.it
```

Then, I insert the password and I can have the access to the system.
I load anaconda module with the following script:

```
module load anaconda/3.7
```

I activate 'myenv' environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

I run this code to access jupyter notebook:

```
(myenv) [a06upi0e@login09 ~]$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8888
```

This is the output:

```
[W 17:38:56.844 NotebookApp] Loading JupyterLab as a classic notebook (v6) extension.
[W 2023-02-17 17:38:56.853 LabApp] 'ip' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2023-02-17 17:38:56.853 LabApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2023-02-17 17:38:56.853 LabApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2023-02-17 17:38:56.853 LabApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2023-02-17 17:38:56.872 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /g100/home/usera06upi/a06upi0e/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2023-02-17 17:38:56.873 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /g100/home/usera06upi/a06upi0e/.conda/envs/myenv/share/jupyter/lab
[I 17:38:56.893 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /g100/home/usera06upi/a06upi0e
[I 17:38:56.893 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.2 is running at:
[I 17:38:56.894 NotebookApp] http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2c11ef7864a2804cae3b0f650527067f5420778909baf5e1
[I 17:38:56.894 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2c11ef7864a2804cae3b0f650527067f5420778909baf5e1
[I 17:38:56.894 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 17:38:56.920 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///g100/home/usera06upi/a06upi0e/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-22202-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2c11ef7864a2804cae3b0f650527067f5420778909baf5e1
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2c11ef7864a2804cae3b0f650527067f5420778909baf5e1
```

Then, from another terminal on local I run this:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8889:localhost:8888 a06upi0e@cometa.hpc.cineca.it
```

It askes me to enter the password related to the HPC remote system. So, I enter the password

```
a06upi0e@cometa.hpc.cineca.it's password:
```

And I open this link (http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2c11ef7864a2804cae3b0f650527067f5420778909baf5e1) to the browser. The problem is that I cannot get the access to the link: it says to me that it's impossible to reach the website.

What should I do? I tried changing ports but without succeeding.

Comment: set up the ssh port forwarding BEFORE starting jupyter, not after. ie run `ssh -N -f -L localhost:8889:localhost:8888 a06upi0e@cometa.hpc.cineca.it` first.

Comment: I tried to do it, but I receive the same error when I open the link of the notebook on the browser: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` with the port `8889`, and `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` with other ports.